# read php script and print in browser and write current date into the file?

Tags: php

I have a text file, I want to read a file and write current date into the text file.
    myfile.txt
    HELLO WORLD
I will print this file in browser.  Now I want to write current date to the file.

```
mydate.php
<? php
$file = "myfile.txt"
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if!($handle){
$date = new DateTime();
fwrite($handle, $date);
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

The above is my php script and want to write current date to the text file. Please help what I need to do to write the date to the file?? Thanks

Comment: took at the **r** in [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: ^ + Look at [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Dagon, could you please explain how to do that...

Comment: explain how to read the manual page i linked to ?

Comment: @Rana Click on the link?!

Comment: `$date = new DateTime();` "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"

Comment: Yes Pedro, that's what the error i'm getting right now. fwrite parameter 2 cannot be converted to string.

Comment: @Rana Did you even read my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019957/read-php-script-and-print-in-browser-and-write-current-date-into-the-file#comment48157310_30019957 ?

Comment: Hi @Rizier123, I'm sorry about that. I have visited the link you provided. I'm working on it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`

```
$myFile = "myfile.txt";
$myFileContents = file_get_contents($myFile); // $myFileContents now holds the content of myFile.txt
```

if you want to append the current date to `myFile.txt` you can use:

```
$myFile = "myFile.txt";
$myDate = date("m j Y");
file_put_contents($myFile,$myDate, FILE_APPEND);
```

---

Learn more about [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) 
,
[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Alright Pedro. I will check with the above syntax and will revert back to you.Thanks to all.

Comment: Happened to me too.  I think it was someone that didn't like us trying to help too much.  I would suspect Rizier123 or Dragon

Comment: I know a bit @Rizier123 and I'm sure he would comment before down-vote and I guess Dragon  too. No problem, it happens sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "myfile.txt"
```

Change:

```
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
```

To:

```
$handle = fopen($file, "a");
```

Remove:

```
if!($handle){
```

Change:

```
 $date = new DateTime();
```

To:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');


fwrite($handle, $date);
fclose($handle);
```

Final:

```
$file = "myfile.txt"
$handle = fopen($file, "a");
$date = date('Y-m-d');
fwrite($handle, $date);
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code finally worked!!

```
<?php
//get contents of a file
$file = "myfile.txt";
$doc = file_get_contents($file);
echo $doc;
$handle = fopen($file,"a");
ini_alter('date.timezone','America/Chicago');
$date = date(DATE_RFC2822);
fwrite($handle, $date . "\n");
fclose($handle);
?>
```